# CSS code a:visited does not work

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a pretty noob problem, so I hope someone could help me out.

I have a Blogger blog, and I can't get the links to function like I want to.

I want the links in the post content and in the sidebar - the ones that are a purple shade (#8B7083) and underlined - to look the same for both a:link and a:visited. For some reason visited links turn black, even though I don't have that anywhere in my CSS.

Help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *do* have it in your CSS:

```
 .popular-posts .item-title a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
      color: black !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
 }
```

Try not to use the `!important` keyword, it overrides all other styles. Use specificity to determine what styles to apply where: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Looking at your selectors, I believe you might not be constructing them as you intend. Are you looking for this?

```
  .popular-posts .item-title a:link, .popular-posts .item-title a:hover,  .popular-posts .item-title a:active, .popular-posts .item-title a:visited
```

As it stands, your last three segments in your selector (a:hover, a:active, and a:visited) are selecting *all* links on those pages with those states as you are not constraining them via a descendent selector.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that only for the popular-posts and item-title class?

Comment: No, `.popular-posts .item-title a:link` is just for the popular posts, but you have `a:hover, a:active, a:visited`, which will affect the `a` styling `globally`, unless it is overridden.

Comment: Thanks, Chris and Nick. I didn't realise that.